# Qt Qml source code formatting unwanted behaviour

Tags: qt, qml, qt-creator, code-formatting

I want to customize source code formatting for Qt QML.

In Qt Examples they use source code format like below :

```
Text {
    id: typeSomething
    anchors.fill: parent; anchors.leftMargin: 8
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
    text: "Type something..."
    color: "gray"
    font.italic: true
    font.pointSize: 14
}
```

I think it has some readability issues, it looks like a mess to me.

I use this style to prevent this readability issue :

```
Text {
    id                 :   typeSomething
    anchors.fill       :   parent; 
    anchors.leftMargin :   8
    verticalAlignment  :   Text.AlignVCenter
    text               :   "Type something..."
    color              :   "gray"
    font.italic        :   true
    font.pointSize     :   14
}
```

It seems much cleaner than previous one. When I indent manually like this and formatting the file there is no problem. It keeps indents and stay same.

But there is another option as far as I see it is best indentation for qml ( or any declarative syntax )

```
Text {
                    id:   typeSomething
          anchors.fill:   parent; 
    anchors.leftMargin:   8
     verticalAlignment:   Text.AlignVCenter
                  text:   "Type something..."
                 color:   "gray"
           font.italic:   true
        font.pointSize:   14
}
```

It can be seen a bit messier than previous one, but it is practically more readable than both first and second example. When I type like this and I do 'code formatting' of QtCreator, it converts the indentation to the first example. So it looks like this :

```
 Text {
    id:   typeSomething
    anchors.fill:   parent; 
    anchors.leftMargin:   8
    verticalAlignment:   Text.AlignVCenter
    text:   "Type something..."
    color:   "gray"
    font.italic:   true
    font.pointSize:   14
}
```

Those thoughts are my personal view and it is not topic of the question.

My question is how can I keep indentation of latest example when I do 'code formatting' in QtCreator ?

Comment: Note that adding/removing a property, if it has the longest name, would require a complete reformatting and thus produce unreadable patches/diffs.

Comment: You can activate Beautifier plugin and so use one of available options like Artistic style, Clang, Uncrustify etc. Each one of the has option to specify that you want.